# Showing calls if my list of strings is like the entity column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

```
List<sring> MyList = new List<string>();

string MyUser = "James Wilson"

MyList.Add(MyUser);
```

My Model Entity the column is `call_to`

```
"User 1 (Claims)"
"User 2 (Department3)"
"James Wilson (Development)"
"User 4"
"User 2"
"James Wilson (Development)"

model.where(w => MyList.Contains(w.call_to)).select(s => s)
```

Now this returns back to me 0 calls because call_to shows me as `"James Wilson (Development)`

I have verified this is the issue because when I change it to be this:

```
model = model.Where(w => MyList.Contains(w.call_from.Replace("(Development)", "").Trim()));
```

It returns just the calls I am attached to like it should.

So my question is, how can I make it see if `call_from` just contains my name and not matches it exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your statement ...

```
model.Where(w => MyList.Contains(w.call_to))
```

... `Contains` only matches if `MyList` contains a string that exactly matches `w.call_to`. Instead, you should check if `MyList` contains at least one string (*any* string) that *contains* `w.call_to`:

```
model.Where(w => MyList.Any(s => s.Contains(w.call_to)))
```

Be careful though. This only works well if `MyList` is not too long. EF has to convert the list into SQL, which takes a lot of generated code that slows down query execution. Check the generated SQL to see what I mean.

Side note: the `.Select(s => s)` part is redundant.

Comment: Thanks I was able to get that to work, and also I always wondered about the .Select part.  Kudos!